# What is $h^0(O(m)_V)$, where $V\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^n$ is a degree $d$ hypersurface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am trying to compute the number of section of the restriction of the line bundle $O(m)$ to a hyper-surface $V$, given by a degree $d$ polynomial. I cannot figure out how to do this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you meant $m$ and not $n$ for the twist  and $n\geq 2$. You have an exact sequence, $0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-d)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to\mathcal{O}_V\to 0$. Thus, we get $h^0(\mathcal{O}_V(m))=h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m))-h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m-d))$, which I am sure you know how to calculate.

Comment: @Mohan I have correct it thanks. Now we can just use $h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m))=\binom{n+m}{m}$?

Comment: I've answered a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020065/compute-the-cohomology-of-projective-schemes/1020183#1020183).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you. I had specifically said that I am assuming $n\geq 2$ in my answer. Beginners get flustered when one invokes higher cohomologies, so I avoided it.